# Sign out with ex-navigation using DrawerNavigation

Tags: react-native, exponentjs

I built my navigation based on [Ex-navigation's example](https://github.com/exponentjs/ex-navigation/tree/master/example)

Everything is working as expected, but I don't know how to Sign out

I have a `<Main/>` component which renders a `<DrawerNavigationMenu/>` as in the example
.This is my `<DrawerNavigationMenu/>`

```
render() {
return (
  <DrawerNavigation
    renderHeader={this._renderHeader}
    drawerWidth={300}
    initialItem="home">
    <DrawerNavigationItem
      id="home"
      selectedStyle={styles.selectedItemStyle}
      renderTitle={isSelected => this._renderTitle('Home', isSelected)}
      renderIcon={isSelected => this._renderIcon('md-home', isSelected)}>
      <StackNavigation
        id="home"
        defaultRouteConfig={{
          navigationBar: {
            backgroundColor: '#2497b7',
            tintColor: '#fff',
            height: 60,
          },
        }}
        initialRoute={Router.getRoute('home')}/>
    </DrawerNavigationItem>

    <DrawerNavigationItem
      id="logout"
      selectedStyle={styles.selectedItemStyle}
      renderTitle={isSelected => this._renderTitle('Logout', isSelected)}
      renderIcon={isSelected => this._renderIcon('md-exit', isSelected)}>
      <StackNavigation
        id="root"
        initialRoute={Router.getRoute('root')}/>
    </DrawerNavigationItem>
  </DrawerNavigation>
);
}
```

In the "logout" item **I need to reset the navigation stack** and render my Root scene without the chance of going back

I tried using `initialStack=` instead of `initialRoute=`, like this

```
<StackNavigation
 id="root"
 initialStack={[Router.getRoute('root')]}/>
```

But when I hit (Android)back, it still going back to Home scene. I'm not using Redux explicitly here. Is this the right way to implement a sign out navigation? Any ideas? Please!

Answer (score 1):

Give DrawernavigationItem props `onPress` and call a function that switches between Authentication and Landing pages.

```
<DrawerNavigationItem
     id="Sign out"
     selectedStyle={styles.selectedItemStyle}
     onPress={()=>{this.signOut()}}
     renderTitle={isSelected => this._renderTitle('Sign out', isSelected)}
   />
```